# JSDOM: dom.window.document.innerHTML is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdom

I am creating a node.js script to parse the content from a website. Before I work with the returned HTML I want to remove a few elements and properties. However, when trying to retrieve the HTML from jsdom I am only returned `undefined`. This appears to happen before I make my modifications to the HTML. How can I use jsdom to modify the HTML and return it?

```
const jsdom = require('jsdom');
...
var htmlString = `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"><html lang=en><head>...`
paresHTML(htmlString);

function parseHTML(htmlString) {
    const dom = new jsdom.JSDOM(htmlString);

    console.log(dom.window.document.innerHTML); // This returns undefined

    dom.window.document.querySelectorAll('script').forEach(element => element.remove());
    dom.window.document.querySelectorAll('head').forEach(element => element.remove());
    dom.window.document.querySelectorAll('link').forEach(element => element.remove());
    dom.window.document.querySelectorAll('style').forEach(element => element.remove());
    dom.window.document.querySelectorAll('iframe').forEach(element => element.remove());

    dom.window.document.querySelectorAll('noscript').forEach((element) => {
        var replacement = dom.window.document.createElement('div');
        replacement.setAttribute('class', 'noscript');
        replacement.innerHTML = element.innerHTML;
        element.parentNode.replaceChild(replacement, element);
    });

    dom.window.document.querySelectorAll('img[src]').forEach((element) => {
        const src = element.getAttribute('src');
        element.setAttribute('data-src', src);
        element.removeAttribute('src');
    });

    dom.window.document.querySelectorAll('[style]').forEach((element) => {
        element.removeAttribute('style');
    });

    return dom.window.document.innerHTML; // This also returns undefined
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like on the front-end, the `document` has no `innerHTML` property:

```js
console.log(document.innerHTML);
```

However, the `document.documentElement` does have it:

```js
console.log(document.documentElement.innerHTML);
```

JSDom works the same way. Adding `.documentElement` to the `document` accesses, eg

```
console.log(dom.window.document.documentElement.innerHTML);
```

results in:

```
<head></head><body>...</body>
```